# Changing layout_height to "wrap_content" shrinks components

Tags: android, android-layout

I understand it is best practice to have layout_width set to "match_parent" and layout_height set to "wrap_content" for each component in the UI to ensure proper scaling across devices, portrait view and landscape view. However, setting layout_height to "wrap_content" causes each element to shrink. How can I keep elements at their desired sizes and still ensure proper scaling?

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image]

After

Answer (score 1):

It's not a rule of thumb that you always define `layout_width` `match_parent` and height `wrap_content` for each component. it all depends on your design.

To provide good graphical qualities on devices with different pixel densities, you should provide multiple versions of each image in your app—one for each density bucket, at a corresponding resolution. Otherwise, Android must scale your image so it occupies the same visible space on each screen, resulting in scaling artifacts such as blurring.

There are several density buckets available for use in your apps.

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
xxhdpi  Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi).
xxxhdpi Resources for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi).
nodpi   Resources for all densities.
```

These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current screen's density.

or you can use SVG vector instead of PNG it will reduce the size of APK.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Comment: Thanks! I'm not concerned with images here, though. I just need to figure out how to make something like a Button or a ScrollBar keep the same width and height on every device.